# How to run sqlcmd.exe from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sqlcmd

I'm trying this and it's failing

```
PS C:\Users\MooMin>$i = "MySQLInstanceName"
PS C:\Users\MooMin>& sqlcmd -S $i -E -q"SELECT @@VERSION"
```

I get this error:

```
Unrecognized token in source text.
At line:1 char:31
+ & sqlcmd -S "$i" -E -q"SELECT  <<<< @@VERSION"
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnrecognizedToken
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A space is missing between `-q` and tsql statement. Try like so,

```
sqlcmd -S $i -E -q "SELECT @@VERSION"
```

Comment: Interesting that it works in cmd.exe without the space, but not in PowerShell